# Get into Docker container CLI and run multiple commands

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I have multiple commands(more than 15) to run inside docker image CLI. I need to get inside docker image bash and run commands and exit after completion. I don't want to use `docker exec <container_name> <command>` before every commands. Because I have dynamic parameters for commands. Is there any way to achieve this?

For Example, I need to execute below commands inside CLI.

```
export ORDERER_CA=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer0.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem && export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel
peer channel fetch 0 mychannel.block -o orderer0.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA
peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

I am trying to execute the commands from outside using a shell script.

Comment: Why don't you put the commands into a shell script, copy it into the container and execute that?

Comment: Use a heredoc? [Example](https://gist.github.com/mbreese/e6d4b57867ca440341b5).

Comment: yes @daniu, I am trying that one. But once I am doing `export` for the environment variable next time when I am getting into a bash that environment variable is not available.

Comment: @Cyrus good solution. But not working for me. The files are exported outside of the container. Thanks.